# Powershell how to subtract a variable from another variable, both contain the Exchange Mailbox Object Identity

Tags: powershell, set, exchange-server

I have two variables both which contain the `Get-Mailbox` object `"Identity"` of user accounts. I need to subtract the contents of one from the other IE:

```
$termednofwd = (domain.local/OUname/SubOU/Users/first1 last1, domain.local/OUname/SubOU/first2 last2)

$termedfmr = (domain.local/OUname/SubOU/Users/first1 last1)
```

I want something that would subtract the contents of `$termedfmr` from `$termednofwd` giving something like the below. `Compare-Object` only lists the contents that are in both, I basically need to subtract what is in both from the first variable.
essentially:
`$termednofwdnofmr = $termednofwd - $termedfmr` resulting in this:

```
$termednofwdnofmr = (domain.local/OUname/SubOU/first2 last2)
```

Comment: Please consider something like [Replace Text with PowerShell](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-replace/) first. There are syntax issues with all of your posted code so it adds a layer of confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In set theory terms, you're looking for the *relative complement* between two collections, which [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) *can* provide, although it requires additional effort:

By default, `Compare-Object` provides the *symmetric difference* between two sets, i.e. it lists the *union* of relative complements; that is, given two sets A and B, it lists *both* those elements of B not present in A *and* those elements of A not present in B, and it uses the `.SideIndicator` property to indicate which is which:

- `'<='` indicates objects unique to set A (`-ReferenceObject` argument, or first *positional* argument), whereas
- `'=>'` indicates elements unique to set B (`-DifferenceObject` argument, or second positional argument).

Therefore, you need to filter the output objects by their `.SideIndicator` values.
The `-PassThru` switch additionally ensures that the input objects are passed through (as opposed to wrapping them in a `[pscustomobject]` instance whose `.InputObject` contains them):

```sh
$termednofwd = 'domain.local/OUname/SubOU/Users/first1 last1',
               'domain.local/OUname/SubOU/first2 last2'

$termedfmr = 'domain.local/OUname/SubOU/Users/first1 last1'

# Return the elements in $termednofwd that aren't also present in $termedfmr
Compare-Object $termednofwd $termedfmr -PassThru |
  Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<='
```

The above yields `'domain.local/OUname/SubOU/first2 last2'`, i.e. those element(s) in `$termednofwd` that aren't also present in `$termedfmr`.

Note: The above uses *strings* as input objects for brevity; in your case, since you're working with the objects returned by the `Get-Mailbox` cmdlet and want to compare based on their `.Identity` property values, you need to use:

```sh
# If you only need the identity values as results.
Compare-Object $termednofwd.Identity $termedfmr.Identity -PassThru |
  Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<='

# Alternatively, if you need the whole mailbox objects.
Compare-Object -Property Identity $termednofwd $termedfmr -PassThru |
  Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<='
```

See also: [GitHub issue #4316](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4316), which proposes enhancing `Compare-Object` with *set operations*.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Brandon. My example used strings for brevity. I've updated the answer to include your solution, including an alternative where you get the whole mailbox objects in the results, by using `-Property Identity` instead.

Answer (score 0):

So this is essentially a practical example of Set theory i.e. I'd like all the items from Set 1 that isn't in Set 2.  PowerShell doesn't have direct commandlets to do that but through the power of .Net you can lervage the Microsoft Linq libraries to do this work for you.

The only trick is that you need to cast your PowerShell variables to arrays of Objects to make the function call work right:

```
$results = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Except([object[]]$mainArray, [object[]]$subArray)
```

Lastly, the items you are comparing in the two arrays have to be comparable.  For simple things like strings this is always works.  If the things you are comparing are more complex objects, they may not be comparable directly.